# Is it worth putting in pot lights for the shower/tub area from the developer as an upgrade?

Tags: lighting, bathroom, light-fixture, recessed-lighting, bathroom-fixtures

I bought a new condo and in the phase of choosing structural upgrades. They have an option for adding potlights to a bathroom shower/tub area. The only other source of light is the vanity light on top of the mirror, so that won't be enough for the shower/tub area.

The developer cost is 1700 CAD $ to put in each potlight (I have 2 bathrooms).

Question is, is it worth getting the upgrade from the developer or getting a contractor to put it in after? Keep in mind, I only plan to live in there for a few years and then resell so I need it to look perfect and not hacky or different paint colors everywhere from cutting walls, etc...

I have no access to attic or top of ceiling since its a condo, and have no idea how the wiring is. I'm pretty sure there is no pre wiring where the potlight would go.

Can anyone explain, if I were to have a contractor doing this, how would they be able to install it?

Thanks

EDIT:

My condo bathroom looks like this. The red x's are where the vanity lights are. One of them is a standing shower with glass door, the other is a tub with an opaque shower curtain.
[image]

Comment: `the vanity light on top of the mirror, so that won't be enough for the shower/tub area.` Must be a huge bathroom, then. Works fine in almost every normal-sized bathroom I've been in.

Comment: It does work, but with the curtains it can get dark, so a potlight in the shower is preferred also for resale. But its also not a large bathroom, just regular size, sink/toilet/shower, you get in a 700 square feet condo.

Comment: Only if you're trapped into using their guy because it's an association. Do you take your car back to the dealer for repairs, or do you shop around and save 75%? For $1,300 a light, I'm available.

Comment: "Opaque shower curtain" - That's easily changed for one that allows light through.

Comment: For 1700 per light, I would want them handmade by master light builder and made out of very expensive materials(gold, platinum).  Light, materials(wire) and electrician maybe 400 per light(probably cheaper).

Answer (score 2):

There is *always* a way to install more lighting fixtures. It is easiest to do this before the drywall is up, but $1,700 CAD *per light* sounds like an awful lot to me. The fixtures and wiring generally cost very little - the real cost is labor. My hunch is the developer is betting on people (a) willing to roll all the upgrades into the mortgage and forget about the little details since they're not literally paying the amount directly and/or (b) not wanting to have to hire someone else afterwards to do extra work.

How much would a professional licensed electrician charge? That's a good question, but my guess is a *lot* less than $1,700 per light. However, there is a catch: Adding lights to a finished area generally requires opening up the walls and/or ceiling and patching/painting afterwards. That cost can be significant. But still $1,700 sounds high.

I would also look at what else is in the bathroom ceiling. A fan is generally recommended, even though not required if you have a window that you can open for ventilation. So the usual solution is to install a combination fan/light, or even combination fan/heater/light. If your bathrooms include fans, it *should* be relatively easy for an electrician to replace fan with fan/light with minimal, if any, patching/painting needed.

A middle option is to add a ceiling fixture that is powered by the vanity light. This will require less work because you don't need to run a new cable all the way to the switch box. The only trick is getting from the vanity light up into the ceiling. That may require cutting a hole into the wall near the ceiling (or into the ceiling near the wall), which would then require patching and painting.

One other thing to keep in mind. Normally ceiling lights and fans do *not* require GFCI protection. However, if a light is above a tub/shower then it will likely require GFCI protection. The usual solution (works in my bathrooms) is to have the fan/light just outside the tub/shower, but close enough that plenty of light gets into the tub/shower over the curtain.

Comment: You are right and its a 25% deposit, and then the rest goes into mortgage. There is no window in the bathroom, but I also don't know if there is a fan. I will try to find out tomorrow. I didn't know there was a light/fan combo, that would be interesting, but if its in the center of the bathroom, I am not sure it is still enough. I'll post a picture of the bathroom on top actually in a minute. Is it possible to have a kind of light track/fan option so the light starts from the middle but then extends into the bathroom? Maybe a waterproof one.

Comment: I have added the picture above if that helps.

Comment: There are all kinds available. I'd be shocked if a window-less bathroom in Canada wasn't required to have a fan.

Comment: Would a good option be to make the vanity lights dimmable, and then get a very powerful bulb?

Comment: You could do that. But if it comes down to relying in some way on the vanity lights, run a cable from the vanity lights up to the ceiling (shouldn't be far) and over to the middle of the bathroom and put in a light fixture that is then controlled by the same switch as the vanity light. Not as convenient (you can't have vanity on, ceiling off or vice versa) but still a decent solution. I'll add it to the answer.